# Java Swing Controls: very small when minimized?

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, sizing

I have a Swing JFrame with some controls in a GridLayout.

My problem is that the controls (Text fields) appear too small when the frame is minimized. I tried to avoid this by setting:

```
setPreferredSize
```

and

```
setSize
```

but still, I have to maximize the frame to see the controls clearly.

How can I solve this ?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe. See also [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No code is posted, but it is possible that you're not constructing the textfields with specified number of columns. `setPreferredSize` or `setSize` are not needed, try this instead:

```
JTextField tf = new JTextField(30)
```

which will create a textfield of fixed size (columns) 30. This way your textfields will not shrink or expand.